# SQL Group By error ORA-00979

Tags: sql, oracle10g, ora-00979

I'm trying to give this query:

```
select s_name, course from Student group by course;
```

But I get an error (ORA-00979 Not a GROUP BY EXPRESSION).

I want to list the names of all the students that are in the same course.
Is there another method of doing this? If not, what is the proper way to implement this query? I would appreciate if someone could give me the exact code required.

Comment: s_name should be in the GROUP BY or remove it from the select list

Comment: I really don't understand SQL that well, could you please type the exact code?

Comment: I want to list the names of all the students (contained in 's_name') who are from the same course (contained in 'course'). I believe a 'grouping' command can do this job, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The exact code depends on what you want

Comment: Do you want all of the students in a *specific* course? Maybe you just meant to `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY`, or maybe you meant `WHERE course = <something>`. It doesn't sound like grouping is what you want here.

Comment: I want that the names should appear in groups, like all the students from course ABC should appear as a group, then DEF, then GHI, and so on... Is that possible?

Comment: Then you indeed want sorting (ORDER BY), not grouping.

Answer (score 2):

One variant (Oracle 11g):

```
select course, listagg(s_name, ', ') within group (order by s_name) 
 from student
group by course;
```

Oracle 10g (undocumented secret function **wm_concat**)

```
select course, wm_concat(s_name)
 from student
group by course;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I didn't know that I had to use ORDER BY, instead of GROUP BY for the desired effect.

Comment: @Don't be Evil Irony It's ok I haven't known that wm_concat exists so it was useful for me.

Comment: Holy moly, that brings and even better result, but my teachers wouldn't even understand the secret wm_concat function. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want you shouldn't use `GROUP BY`.
The intention of GROUP BY is to summarise information per group.

Since you want detail within each course, you should rather use `ORDER BY` to ensure that your output is simply sorted with students in the same course listed together.

```
select  s_name, course
from    Student
order by course
```

For an example of what `GROUP BY` is intended for, try the following:

```
select  course, COUNT(*) as NumStudents
from    Student
group by course
```

Comment: Thanks. I finally got where GROUP BY expression is used and how, thanks to the simplified example you gave.